# Network architecture understanding using keras code

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

My data is of 68871 x 43, where the features are in the column no. 1-43 and each label is represented as a 1x21 vector

In my keras code:

- print trainX.shape -----> (41311, 10, 43)
- print trainY.shape -----> (41311, 21)
- print testX.shape  ------> (27538, 10, 43)
- print testY.shape  ------> (27538, 21)

When I run the following keras code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_dim=43))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(21, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_split=0.20, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
scores = model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

The code executes like this [image]

My understanding for the keras toolkit is that, if the 3D tensor for trainX is of the shape (41311,10,43) then keras should create a lstm with 10 timestep. If this is so then why are the samples in the screenshot run one by one; if the timestep is 10 then it should have run in the batches of 10 and get 10 prediction and then run the next 10 batches of samples.

Anyone can answer me: why the screenshot shows the samples run one by one when the timestep is 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sample they understand a numpy array of shape (10,43). The first dimension is your number of samples.

So what the network is doing is :
1) split the input into batches of shape (batch, 10, 43)

2) feed the lstm, one sample at a time. A sample being a sequence of 10 events/tensors of length 43 each. So each sequence is 1 sample.

Is that clear?

Comment: so the network would wait for 10 events/tensors to be fed in before generating the first prediction (and so on upto 10 predictions)?

Comment: Nope, the way you built it is : 1 input = 1 sequence of 10 tensors of length 43. Another way to say it : 1 input = 1 2D tensor of shape (10,43). And you have 33048 of them because it is 80% of 41311.

Comment: Ok, this is clear to me, thanks so much. I have a different question which is: the lstm would start giving predictions just after the first 2D tensor of shape (10,43) is fed into it (or) it will wait for the 10th 2D tensor of shape (10,43) to be fed before giving the first prediction?

Comment: No. The input of LSTM's are sequences of vectors, so their inputs are 2D arrays. The first dimension is the number of vectors in the sequences and the second is the length of those vectors. So it will eat the fiest vector of your (10,43) input which means a vector of size 43, then it will eat the second one, then the third, until 10th vector. Once the whole (10,43) input is processed it outputs something... in your case you asked for a vector of length 10 as output of the LSTM.

Comment: If my answers are satisfying to you don't forget to upvote and accept the answer as good :-) thanks

Comment: **Ok thanks, your answer are satisfying**. Can you tell me a source from where I can confirm this (by this I mean: once the whole (10,43) input is processed it outputs something).

Comment: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/ look at input and output. They mention 3D input, the first dimension is the batch size. In your case since batch_size =1 you have inputs that have the shape (1,10,43) and output (1,10)

Comment: What actually happens when **stateful=FLASE** ? I guess the first 2D tensor of shape (10,43) would be recognized by the lstm and then the second 2D tensor of shape (10,43) would be recognized by the lstm and the hidden representations learned during the recognition of first 2D tensor won't be used during the recognition of second 2D tensor. ??

Comment: If stateful=False (it's default), the output is one vector of length 10 in your case (last state). If stateful=True it outputs the states at every steps so the output will be a 2D tensor of shape (10,10). But man, just read the doc on the link I sent you or take machine learning classes, i'm not here to make a course abourt data science....